# Excel dynamic drop down List by filtered table

Tags: excel, validation, drop-down-menu, excel-formula

Hi I have a problem with the data validation list in Excel.

First of all I have one table(named: Article) in a protected Tab with four attributes (Name, Sex, Colour, Price). It is possible that two or more articles have the same name and differ by Sex (male or female) or by colour.

```
Name         | Sex       | Colour     | Price
-------------|-----------|------------|---------
Product1     | Male      | Blue       | 10
Product1     | Male      | Green      | 10
Product1     | Female    | Pink       | 5
Product2     | Male      | Grey       | 8
Product2     | Female    | Orange     | 8
```

In the main Tab I organized the order in an different table (called: Order).

```
Product      | Sex       | Colour     | Quantity   | Price
-------------|-----------|------------|------------|---------
<List>       | <List>    | <List>     |            | <Calculation>
```

The dropdown List for Product (Data Validation | List | Source -> =INDIREKT("Article[Name]"))

and Sex (Data Validation | List | Source -> Male; Female) is easy.

But how I get a list for Colour - depended on Productname and Sex?

For example Product = Product1 and Sex = Male the drop down for colour should contain Blue and Green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change the structure of your table. Either copy and transpose this with an array formula, entered as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=TRANSPOSE(TABLE)
```

You need your table in the following form:

```
Product 1 | Product2 | Product 3

Green     | Grey     | Pink

Blue      | Orange   | White
```

Then, you define each of those columns as a named range. You can select the entire table and go to Formulas > Create from selection (in the Defined Names section). Mark only "Top row" and click ok. Now you have named ranges you can use in your dependent or cascading dropdown list. In this one, your source will be:

```
=INDIRECT(A1) 'Replace A1 with the location of your first-level dropdownlist
```

Of course, it becomes considerably more complicated if you need to add an extra condition to your secondary dropdown. Firstly, your table needs to be in the following structure:

```
Product 1Male | Product1Female | Product 2Male | Product 2Female

Green         | Grey           | Pink          | Red

Blue          | Orange         | White         | Pink
```

And the formula for your dependent dropdown would be:

```
=INDIRECT(A1&A2) 'Where A1 and A2 are the locations of your other 2 dropdown lists.
```

That should work as you need it. Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me, but just for a general understanding. There is no possibility to get a list or array of all items that match two or more attributes? Like a Select with where clause in sql?

Comment: What you want is definitely doable - enter into a range that has as many rows as your "Article" table: `=IF(((Article[Name]=A1)*(Article[Sex]=A2))=1,Article[Color],"")` (A1 and A2 are the cells with your Product and Sex, respectively) as an array formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**. However, Excel doesn't allow you to use array formulas in a data validation, which is why I didn't mention this in the original solution. You COULD add this into a helper column in a hidden sheet and base your data validation on this column, but I don't know if that would work for you.

Comment: Also, note that this helper column will include several blank rows, you can see how to delete these here http://www.get-digital-help.com/2007/09/16/excel-remove-blank-cells/#array and then base your data validation on `=OFFSET($B$1,0,0,SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(B:B)>0)))`