# How to create DropDown which have dynamic Validation List

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have data table with columns 'Category' and 'Product'. Product names are not unique, Category names are not unique, but the combination Category-Product appears just once in table. This data table is NOT sorted in any way.

```
Category  Product

========  =======

Chairs      Victorian

Chairs      Beautiful

Chairs      Edwardian

Chairs      Gross

Tables      Victorian

Tables      Edwardian

Tables      Huge

Tables      Kool

Tables      Lambda

Closets     Edwardian

Closets     Excellent

Closets     Major

Closets     Hello

Chairs      Huge

Tables      Picturesque

Closets     Picturesque

Chairs      Incredible

Closets     Minor

Chairs      Just

Chairs      Kool
```

I have already created temporary table with unique Category names, which will be used as validation range for the first dropdown list. This part works as it should.

```
Categories

==========

Chairs

Tables

Closets
```

Next to the first dropdown, I have another dropdown which should have dynamically created list of products of the category selected in previous dropdown.

If it is just for one pair of dropdowns (Category/Product), I can create satisfactory result using temporary columns.

```
Category:   Chairs           Product: Victorian

                                                  Beautiful

                                                  Edwardian

                                                  Gross

                                                  Huge

                                                  . . .
```

The problem is that this dropdown pairs should be part of another table with columns: 'Category', 'Product', 'Amount'. So, when user chooses in first column Category dropdown value 'Chairs', in the next column dropdown should be available in list just Products from category 'Chairs'. In the next row when the user chooses category 'Tables', in the adjacent cell should be available just products from category 'Tables'.

I am trying to make this using just formulas, array formulas, named functions (do not mix-up them with UDF functions) without VBA code.

Is it possible to do it or I am wasting my time (2 days already)?

Excel file with what I already did: [here](http://www.dropbox.com/s/c6fpux7h4pxhaf5/StackOverflow%20Question.xlsx?dl=0)

**UPDATE (2019-09-30):**

Found this in a comment:
'*However, Excel doesn't allow you to use array formulas in data validation,*' ... by Fernando J. Rivera Nov 4 '17 on [Excel dynamic drop down List by filtered table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103041/excel-dynamic-drop-down-list-by-filtered-table?rq=1)

So, it means that it is **NOT** possible to do dynamic data validation.

Comment: You are not wasting your time as it can be done in Excel but I was surprised that you spent two days without being able to find an answer online... @Pau has pointed the right direction. You just need to create a list for each sub categories and **name** them by the **main category**, and then follow the instructions to create the drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

A way to tackle this problem is to use an `IF` function in the data validation window.

[image: Picture]

```
=IF($F$3=$B$2,$B$3:$B$10,$C$3:$C$10)
```

It checks if cell `F3` of the category column and sees if it matches the string in cell `B2`. If it does, it uses the validation list under the column tables and if it doesn't it takes the other list. This could be extended to closets etc. by nesting IF statements.

Drawback is, as far as I can see now, the validation would have to be done for every row separately.

Comment: This will not work for me. I have hundreds of Categories with hundreds of Products. The Excel file I provided was for demo. Anyway, thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is to create named ranges with the different results I can get from the 1st dropdown. In this case: 3 ranges as on the image below:
[Name assigned to a range excluding the 1st row (where the range name is)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlzLW.png)

Once I have this, I use `INDIRECT` to call the right range as below (considering that your first dropdown is on cell E6):

```
=INDIRECT(E6)
```

[Screenshot of the explained above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oduKr.png)

The only challenge of this method is that if there are many different secondary dropdowns it might be a bit time consuming. With the array formulas that should come in the upcoming updates of Excel (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) this will be way faster and easier (as it is already in google spreadsheets).

Good luck!

Comment: A good answer and I would only suggest you to provide a quick way for the OP to create the separate lists for each main category. For instance using `pivot table`?

Comment: This will not work for me. I have hundreds of Categories with hundreds of Products. The Excel file I provided was for demo. Anyway, thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @TerryW: Pivot table would work, but on each new entry in the table with definition pairs, Pivot should be refreshed - which needs VBA and on_change event and this is what I try to avoid.

Comment: @user1439700 sorry I did not read your question thoroughly. If you want to put hundreds of main categories in a column and put a drop down list of product for each main category next to it, you still need to create as many named ranges as needed for each category. Using power query or pivot table can quickly get you the ranges even for hundreds of categories. The only problem is that either power query or pivot table requires data refresh to update the list for new entries. Otherwise there might be no way achieving what you want even with the beta function **FILTER** in Excel 365...

Comment: 100% with @TerryW: we'll have to wait for the Filter function to be implemented...